# Nav bar don't work in controller in yii2

Tags: yii2

please i have a problem i don't even understand,  am programming with  yii2, and the problem is, I integrated a backend template AdminLTE to my yii2 application, but the dropdown in nav bar won't work in some controller and it will work fine in another.

what i mean is for example the site controller the nav bar has some dropdown menu option and when i click it i can see the drop down menu but when i change to another controller like categories controller or product controller,  the nav bar dropdown menu won't work, and when i click it it won't show dropdown list

i guess it's something inside yii2 conflicting with the js code of the template but i can't fix this i hope i can get some help on this

screenshot 1 (site controller can see dropdown menu)
[image: site controller can see dropdown menu]

screenshot 2 (categories controller can't see dropdown menu)
[image]

screenshot 3 (product controller can't see dropdown menu)
[image]
i'm stuck here for days and really need some help. thanks

Comment: You clikced 3 different link at 3 screeshots. Make sure they all have dropdown content there. Step 1: check the html content, see if there are some content. Step2: Open the console or firebug, see if there are some errors when you click the link. Step 3: Open the html code, check if those three pages all include the correct JS package. No one can figure out the prolem from these 3 screenshots, please post more information.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the bootstrap js files required in your app asset?
If your template uses a widget or something in SiteController that requires BootstrapPluginAsset its included automatically.

Try adding it to your assets/AppAsset.php

Something like this

```
public $depends = [
    'yii\web\YiiAsset',
    'yii\web\JqueryAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset'
];
```